# Haskell forall error

Tags: haskell, eclipse-fp

Eclipse show error in editor at explicit forall, though I can run the script without errors. How can I fix this? (This also happens when I run it in cmd, think I need a flag here!?)

[image]

Also warnings about defaulting to integer type are annoying is there a way to stop them?

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled `{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall #-}` within your file, or where? (Or `ScopedTypeVariables`)

Comment: I should define this in top of the file? Should I define it in each file?!

Comment: What do you need the `forall` for? Unless you don't have a specific need for it you might want to remove it.

Comment: @Doggynub: you certainly need to enable it _somewhere_, the usual options being either in your `project.cabal` file, or on top of each source file.

Comment: how/where should I add it in the .cabal file

Comment: never mind already found how, thanks :)

Comment: @DannyNavarro: The `forall` is probably suggested by an hlint quick fix - my guess is for a missing type signature.

Comment: Yes, this is the case.

Comment: @Doggynub the `forall` is implied here (essentially) and doesn't really do anything in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the language extension in each file like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE FOO #-}
```

where `FOO` is either, `ExplicitForall` which just let's you write `forall`, `ScopedTypeVariables` which means that you can write

```
 foo :: forall a. a -> [a]
 foo a = [a] :: [a]
```

and have the explicit signature work as expected. Or `RankNTypes` which let's you write types of a higher rank like

```
 foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int -> Int
```

In this case it looks like you just want `ExplicitForall`.

Comment: about the defaulting to integer thing It seems you need to remove the -Wall option or specify type of all numbers `1::Int` --- just if any one want to know

Comment: @Doggynub I'm not able to replicate that warning so I can't help you there